# Show profile field on profile page

Tags: users

I created `user-login.tpl.php` file in my custom theme.

Then I add this code :

```
<div class="profile"<?php print $attributes; ?>>
  <h2><?php print ($user_profile['field_nom']);  ?></h2>
  <pre>
    <?php print_r($user_profile); ?>
  </pre>
</div>
```

It display my name correctly but, when I inspect in the browser its look like this ...

```
<h2>
    <div class="field field-name-field-nom field-type-text field-label-above clearfix">

        <div class="field-label">My name:&nbsp;</div>

        <div class="field-items">
            <div class="field-item even">Branquet</div>
        </div>

    </div>
</h2>
```

I just want to have the text, not a bunch of unless divs

Comment: have you tried this $user_profile['field_nom']['und'][0]['value'] ?

Comment: It does not work

Answer (score 1):

One option is you can user php function in tpl file before print.

```
strip_tags($user_profile['field_nom']);
```

Refer http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: It does not work, I did this : $clean = strip_tags($user_profile['field_nom']); print render ($clean);

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user-profile.tpl.php/7) page, there are numerous ways to do this. To render raw field value without any markup use `$account-><YourFieldName>[LANGUAGE_NONE]`

Another way to do this is to preprocess the profile object using [template_preprocess_user_profile](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21user%21user.pages.inc/function/template_preprocess_user_profile/7)

Use any debugging tools to find the raw value of your field

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Semantic Views module](https://www.drupal.org/project/semanticviews)  to strip all the tags.

Comment: This module works along views module. Not for all tpl files.